# Can't call doPost from doGet

Tags: java, servlets

When I'm calling doPost directly, it shows me profile page in correct way. But then after login I open new tab in Chrome copy url "http://localhost:8080/17_servlets_jsp/profile" there and it shows me blank page

```
@WebServlet("/profile")
public class Profile extends HttpServlet {
**private String login;**
private HttpSession httpSession;
private User user;
private Role role;
public static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Profile.class.getName());

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    httpSession = req.getSession();
    try (PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter()) {
        **if (httpSession.getAttribute("userLoggedIn") == null) {
            out.println("<title>Login Page</title>");
            out.println("<p><a href=\"index\">Please follow the link to login</a></p>");
        } else {
            login = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("uLogin");
            doPost(req, resp);
        }**
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    **login = req.getParameter("login");
    user = new ImplUserDAO().findByLogin(login);**
    httpSession = req.getSession();
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    try (PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter()) {
        out.println("<title>Profile page</title>");
        if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(req.getParameter("pass"))) {
            role = new ImplRoleDAO().findById(user.getRoleId());
            httpSession.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", true);
            httpSession.setAttribute("uLogin",req.getParameter("login"));
            httpSession.setAttribute("uPass",req.getParameter("pass"));
            out.println("user id = " + user.getUserId());
            out.println("login = " + user.getLogin());
            out.println("password = " + user.getPassword());
            out.println("role = " + role.getRoleName());
            out.println("<form action=\"logout\" method=\"get\"/>" +
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Logout\"/>" +
                    "</form>");
            if (role.getRoleName().equals("admin")) {
                httpSession.setAttribute("isAdmin", true);
                out.println("<a href=\"admin\">Go to admin page</a>");
            }
        } else {
            out.println("Wrong login or password");
            out.println("<a href=\"index\">Please follow the link to login</a>");
        }
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Visiting http://localhost:8080/17_servlets_jsp/profile should trigger doGet, because it's a get request by definition. What bothers you in this kind of behavior?

Comment: Yes. I knew this, but when I call doGet by this action, I expect to doPost if user logged in or "Please follow the link to login" if user is not logged.

Comment: Get rid of those silly try-catch blocks (it's root cause of your blank page problem) and move HTML code to JSP (it's root cause of forcing yourself to bad practices). Get rid of those request/session based instance variables (not a cause so far, but surely will be in future). Start here to learn how to use servlets the right way: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for response, but this is strict task and I need it without JSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `doPost()` you also execute this line:

```
user = new ImplUserDAO().findByLogin(req.getParameter("login"));
```

Which will throw an `Exception` or return `null` or whatever because your `GET` request didn't include that parameter. If you want to reuse `doPost()` you'd need to fetch login from either session or request:

```
String login = req.getParameter("login");
if(null == login) {
  login = (String)httpSession.getAttribute("uLogin");
}
```

Or similar.

**On Attributes and Parameters**

In your commented out code, you tried to solve this issue by calling `setAttribute("login"...` on your request. While this is legal, you can not retrieve that value by calling `getParameter()`. Instead you'd have to call 'getAttribute()` again - which doesn't make much difference to retrieving directly from the session:

```
//Retrieve Parameter (been send into the servlet from outside)
String login = req.getParameter("login");
if(null == login) {
  //Retrieve Attribute you put into the request in doGet()
  login = (String)req.getAttribute("login");
}
```

**Another Edit**

You have the same issue with `req.getParameter("pass")`.

You should seriously consider splitting login-process (checking username/password from request) from other functionality (display profile page) or **reverse** your logic: Do login, set user into session in `doPost()` and if successful call `goGet()`?

**Full Example Code**

Consider these changes to somewhat fix your logic:

```
@WebServlet("/profile")
public class Profile extends HttpServlet {

    // Don't use member variables on Servlets - they get reused for all users!
    // private String login;
    // private HttpSession httpSession;
    // private User user;
    // private Role role;
    public static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Profile.class.getName());

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    HttpSession httpSession = req.getSession();
    try (PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter()) {
        if (httpSession.getAttribute("userLoggedIn") == null) {
            out.println("<title>Login Page</title>");
            out.println("<p><a href=\"index\">Please follow the link to login</a></p>");            
        } 
        else {
            User user = httpSession.getAttribute("userLoggedIn");
            Role role = httpSession.getAttribute("userRole");

            out.println("<title>Profile page</title>");
            out.println("user id = " + user.getUserId());
            out.println("login = " + user.getLogin());
            out.println("password = " + user.getPassword());
            out.println("role = " + role.getRoleName());
            out.println("<form action=\"logout\" method=\"get\"/>" +
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Logout\"/>" +
                    "</form>");
            if("true".equals(httpSession.getAttribute("isAdmin")) {
                httpSession.setAttribute("isAdmin", true);
                out.println("<a href=\"admin\">Go to admin page</a>");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String login = req.getParameter("login");
        User user = new ImplUserDAO().findByLogin(login);
        HttpSession httpSession = req.getSession();
        try (PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter()) {
            if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(req.getParameter("pass"))) {
                Role role = new ImplRoleDAO().findById(user.getRoleId());
                httpSession.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", user);
                httpSession.setAttribute("userRole", role);
                if (role.getRoleName().equals("admin")) {
                    httpSession.setAttribute("isAdmin", true);
                }
                // Now refer to display part.
                goGet(req, resp);
            } else {
                out.println("Wrong login or password");
                out.println("<a href=\"index\">Please follow the link to login</a>");
            }
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added lines to set this attribute. They're under comment now before calling doPost. This doesnt work. Or I did it wrong

Comment: attributes and parameters are totally different. you can getAttribute() what you setAttribute() but you cannot addParameter() -> this is data from outside. Direct access to session value though might work.

Comment: Sorry, but didnt get you :)

Comment: please define doesn't wok. Error messages? What's (not) happening?

Comment: Oh - you also use password from request... you need to rethink your app logic I think.